# How to get rid of navigations symbols

Tags: navigation, latex, beamer

I read related posts that were addressing the same issue, but I did not find a reply.

I would like to get rid of the navigation symbols, i.e. the small dots below Part One, Part Two, etc.

I tried to use:

> \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

but it does not work.

I also tried to put:

> \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

either before or after the

> begin{document}

but it does not work.

More precisely, when I write the command:

> \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

on TeXStudio it is highlighted in red. When I scroll above it with the mouse I see the message "Unrecognised Message".

I would be very thankful if someone could help me.

Marco

Answer (score 1):

The small dots below the section names are called `mini frames`, `navigation symbols` are the arrows at the bottom right.

The quickest way to remove the mini frames is to set

```
\setbeamertemplate{mini frames}{}
```

However in newer beamer versions this unfortunately leaves the section names vertically misaligned. To repair this one can adjust the headline:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Part one}  
\begin{frame}
xxx
\end{frame} 

\section{Part two}  
\begin{frame}
xxx
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]